# Open UIImagePickerController to custom photo album?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

My app writes to a custom photo album using ALAssetsLibrary. Is there a way to use `UIImagePickerController` to open to my custom album (and preferably only allow viewing of my album)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nope.

This is another one of those annoying limitations with the built-in controls. If it were possible, some insanely smart person on GitHub would build me thing to allow it.

Unfortunately, the `UIImagePickerController` is a private, system class, which doesn't really allow alteration.

What you might do, though, is something like this:

> **Pick an image**
>
> This app stores its images in the 'Unicorn' album.
>
> <kbd>**Choose Image**</kbd>

Comment: Bummer, I suspected as much. Thank you.